# Problema para selecionar um objecto específico dentro de um hash

Tags: array, ruby, select, hash

Olá! Bom dia.
Eu tenho a seguinte situação: No meu código Ruby, há uma classe flor(atributos: **codigo**(gerado por uma função com auto incremento), **nome**, **valor** e **categoria**(este at ributo também representa a key do hash)).

Cada objeto instanciado desta classe é salvo em um objeto chamado Floricultura que é uma instância da classe Floricultura. Na classe floricultura, temos o seguinte código:

```
class Floricultura
  attr_accessor :flores
  def initialize
    @flores = {}
  end

  def adiciona(flor)
    @flores[flor.categoria] ||= []
    @flores[flor.categoria] << flor
  end

  def floresArray
    @flores.values.flatten
  end
```

Onde @flores representa o hash que armazenará cada objecto flor, separando-as por categoria.

No código principal, há um menu e dentre as opções oferecidas, há a opção de apagar uma flor. Para tal, o usuário deverá digitar o valor atribuído ao campo 'código' do objeto flor que será deletado. O sistema deve então pesquisar dentro da hash flores, olhando em cada categoria e em cada objeto contido nela, um que possua valor integer correspondente ao solicitado pelo usuário.
Estou com problemas exatamente no bloco da função responsável por encontrar este valor e apaga-lo.
segue o código:

```
  def opttres
    puts "Digite o código da flor que irá ser apagada: "
    @codigo = gets.chomp
    @floricultura.flores.each do |categoria, flores|
        objeto = flores.select{|flor| flor.codigo == @codigo}
        puts categoria
        puts flores
        puts objeto
        @floricultura.flores[categoria].delete(objeto)
        puts "flor #{objeto} deletada"
    end
  end
end
```

algumas informações:

- a def opttres representa a terceira opção do menu
- se, no final do block select, eu colocar flor.codigo != codigo, ele consegue atribuir a variavel objeto, todas as flores mesmo aquela com o mesmo valor no campo codigo e então, limpa tudo da hash!

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa fazer um select no array e depois deletar, dá para fazer tudo junto com o método [delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) do array:

```
@floricultura.flores.each do |categoria, flores|
   flores.delete_if { |flor| flor.codigo == @codigo }
end
```

Comment: Opa, cara! blz? Então, antes de ver sua resposta, eu consegui solucionar meu problema! Eu poderia ter feito desta maneira que tu mencionou mas como eu queria retornar o nome do objeto selecionado para imprimir na tela "Flor x foi deletada", pensei em incorporar este objeto a uma variavel (no caso, a var objeto). A minha solução foi muito simples:

"@codigo = gets.chomp.to_i" converti para inteiro o valor passado pelo usuario e ai o sistema foi capaz de comparar este valor com o contigo no atributo codigo de cada flor, que é um inteiro!

Comment: @MikhaelAraujo Sem problema cara. O importante é que deu certo! =)